# cannot display uploaded image in a view using twig (symfony2)

Tags: twig

Im working in a project using symfony, and I've a view in which i've to display an image of an entity, i used the same method of the upload recommanded by the documentation, the upload is working fine, but the problem I faced when I want to display the image, I get an exception as following :

```
A hash key must be followed by a colon (:). Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("punctuation" expected with value ":") in StockStockBundle:Payantfournisseur:imprime.html.twig at line 135
```

There is the code that gives me this exception :
In the controller side :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = new Payantfournisseur();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('StockStockBundle:Payantfournisseur')->find($id);
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $societe = new \User\UserBundle\Entity\Societe();
    $societe = $em->getRepository('UserUserBundle:Societe')->find(2);
    //$societe = $user->getSociete();
    $facture = $entity->getIdfacturefournisseur();
    $fournisseur = $facture->getIdfournisseur();
    $articles = $em->getRepository('StockStockBundle:Lignefacturefournisseur')
                       ->getArtFromLines($facture);


    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Devis entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return $this->render('StockStockBundle:Payantfournisseur:imprime.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'fournisseur' => $fournisseur,
        'facture' => $facture,
        'articles' => $articles,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        'societe' => $societe,


            // 'ayoub'=>'yes ayoub',
    ));
```

In the view side :

```
<img src="{{ asset({societe.pjs.getWebPath}) }}" alt="{{ societe.pjs.alt }}" class="spaced img-responsive" />
```

to give more explaination, pjs is a oneToOne related entity with the societe, pjs is the entity responsible for the uploaded files.

If someone has an idea, plz it could be very helpful
thanks in advance!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found parsing error in twig

Remove brace from asset function, use variable like here:

```
<img src="{{ asset(societe.pjs.getWebPath) }}" alt="{{ societe.pjs.alt }}" class="spaced img-responsive" />
```